# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'units'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am working in python and tensor flow but I miss 'units' argument and I do not know how to solve it, It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

here the code

```py
def createModel():
    model = Sequential()
    # first set of CONV => RELU => MAX POOL layers
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=inputShape))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25)) 
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(output_dim=NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax'))
    # returns our fully constructed deep learning + Keras image classifier 
    opt = Adam(lr=INIT_LR, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)
    # use binary_crossentropy if there are two classes
    model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics=["accuracy"])
    return model

print("Reshaping trainX at..."+ str(datetime.now()))
#print(trainX.sample()) 
print(type(trainX)) # <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
print(trainX.shape) # (750,)
from numpy import zeros
Xtrain = np.zeros([trainX.shape[0],HEIGHT, WIDTH, DEPTH])
for i in range(trainX.shape[0]): # 0 to traindf Size -1
    Xtrain[i] = trainX[i]
print(Xtrain.shape) # (750,128,128,3)
print("Reshaped trainX at..."+ str(datetime.now()))

print("Reshaping valX at..."+ str(datetime.now()))
print(type(valX)) # <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
print(valX.shape) # (250,)
from numpy import zeros
Xval = np.zeros([valX.shape[0],HEIGHT, WIDTH, DEPTH])
for i in range(valX.shape[0]): # 0 to traindf Size -1
    Xval[i] = valX[i]
print(Xval.shape) # (250,128,128,3)
print("Reshaped valX at..."+ str(datetime.now()))

# initialize the model
print("compiling model...")
sys.stdout.flush()
model = createModel()

# print the summary of model
from keras.utils import print_summary
print_summary(model, line_length=None, positions=None, print_fn=None)

# add some visualization
from IPython.display import SVG
from keras.utils.vis_utils import model_to_dot
SVG(model_to_dot(model).create(prog='dot', format='svg'))
```

Comment: Can you provide some of the code you wrote? The question is hard to answer till we can see some actual code

Comment: I have wrote the code now

Comment: File "/Users/wafaaladawi/.spyder-py3/DR-kaggle.py", line 265, in createModel
    model.add(Dense(output_dim=NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax'))

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'units'

Comment: plz help me to find the solution

Answer (score 10):

Try changing this line:

`model.add(Dense(output_dim=NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax'))`

to

`model.add(Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax'))`

I'm not experience in keras but I could not find a parameter called `output_dim` on the documentation page for [Dense](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense). I think you meant to provide units but labelled it as output_dim

Answer (score 3):

The Keras Dense layer documentation is as follows:

```
keras.layers.Dense(units, activation=None, use_bias=True, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros', kernel_regularizer=None, bias_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None, kernel_constraint=None, bias_constraint=None)
```

Using the following :

```
classifier.add(Dense(6, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',input_dim=11))
```

Will work as here the units means the output_dim saying that we need 6 neurons in the hidden layer. The weights are initialized with the uniform function and the input layer has 11 independent variables of the dataset (input_dim) to feed the above-hidden layer.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a version issue. In updated version of keras for Dense there is no "output_dim" argument.

You can see this documentation link for Dense arguments.

https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/dense/

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(
    units,
    activation=None,
    use_bias=True,
    kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform",
    bias_initializer="zeros",
    kernel_regularizer=None,
    bias_regularizer=None,
    activity_regularizer=None,
    kernel_constraint=None,
    bias_constraint=None,
    **kwargs
)
```

So the first argument is "units", Which is mandatory.

instead of this line:

```
model.add(Dense(output_dim=NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax'))
```

use this:

```
model.add(Dense(units=NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax'))
```

or

```
model.add(Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax'))
```