# Dense layer : TypeError: init() missing 1 required positional argument: 'units'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


dataset = pd.read_csv('Churn_Modelling.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 3:13]
y = dataset.iloc[:, 13]

geography=pd.get_dummies(X["Geography"],drop_first=True)
gender=pd.get_dummies(X['Gender'],drop_first=True)



X=pd.concat([X,geography,gender],axis=1)


X=X.drop(['Geography','Gender'],axis=1)


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)


from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)



import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LeakyReLU,PReLU,ELU
from keras.layers import Dropout



classifier = Sequential()


classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 6, init = 'he_uniform',activation='relu',input_dim = 11))


classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 6, init = 'he_uniform',activation='relu'))

classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 1, init = 'glorot_uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))

classifier.compile(optimizer = 'Adamax', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])


model_history=classifier.fit(X_train, y_train,validation_split=0.33, batch_size = 10, nb_epoch = 100)



print(model_history.history.keys())

plt.plot(model_history.history['acc'])
plt.plot(model_history.history['val_acc'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

plt.plot(model_history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(model_history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()


y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
y_pred = (y_pred > 0.5)

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
score=accuracy_score(y_pred,y_test)
```

Error:

```
   TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-f92d92e8911e> in <module>
      1 # Adding the input layer and the first hidden layer
      2 
----> 3 classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 6, init = "he_uniform" , activation = 'relu' ,input_dim = 11))

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'units'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Does this answer your question? [TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'units'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56106758/1519716)

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you are using some code that needs Keras < 2.0, you can either downgrade your Keras version, or adapt your code to Keras 2.x.

Reading the [documentation of the Dense layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense?hl=en), you would rewrite:

```
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim=6, init='he_uniform', activation='relu', input_dim=11))
```

to

```
classifier.add(Dense(6, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', activation='relu', input_shape=(11,)))
```

You will have to do that for all the Dense layers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is asking for an additional parameter named 'units', and all you have to do is to replace output_dim into units just as I did below:

**your code:**

`classifier.add(Dense(output_dim=6, init='he_uniform', activation='relu', input_dim=11))`

**corrected:**

`classifier.add(Dense(units=6, init='he_uniform', activation='relu', input_dim=11))`